# How can I create constrained InputStream to read only part of the file?

Tags: java, inputstream

I want to create an InputStream that is limited to a certain range of bytes in file, e.g. to bytes from position 0 to 100. So that the client code should see EOF once 100th byte is reached.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `read()` method of `InputStream` reads a single byte at a time.  You could write a subclass of `InputStream` that maintains an internal counter; each time `read()` is called, update the counter.  If you have hit your maximum, do not allow any further reads (return -1 or something like that).

You will also need to ensure that the other methods for reading `read_int`, etc are unsupported (ex: Override them and just throw UnsupportedOperationException());

I don't know what your use case is, but as a bonus you may want to implement buffering as well.

Comment: I don't think there is any need to implement buffering - that's mixing concerns, and the way read(byte[]) works, returning up to the required amount of data, makes this unnecessary. It's cleaner and equally effective to wrap the base stream in a BufferedInputStream.

Comment: also NB that the only methods in InputStream that are declared abstract are read() and read(byte[], int, int) so sometimes you can get away with just defining those 2 (plus maybe close()) in your child class.

Answer (score 8):

As [danben says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888335/how-can-i-create-constrained-inputstream-to-read-only-part-of-the-file/2888350#2888350), just decorate your stream and enforce the constraint:

```
public class ConstrainedInputStream extends InputStream {
  private final InputStream decorated;
  private long length;

  public ConstrainedInputStream(InputStream decorated, long length) {
    this.decorated = decorated;
    this.length = length;
  }

  @Override public int read() throws IOException {
    return (length-- <= 0) ? -1 : decorated.read();
  }

  // TODO: override other methods if you feel it's necessary
  // optionally, extend FilterInputStream instead
}
```

Comment: Code reuse (BoundedInputStream from commons-io): http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/BoundedInputStream.html

Answer (score 4):

Consider using http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/LimitInputStream.html

Comment: LimitInputStream is scheduled to be removed in Guava release 15.0. Use ByteStreams.limit(java.io.InputStream, long) instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need 100 bytes, then simple is probably best, I'd read them into an array and wrap that as a ByteArrayInputStream. E.g.

```
   int length = 100;
   byte[] data = new byte[length];
   InputStream in = ...;  //your inputstream
   DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(din);
   din.readFully(data);
   ByteArrayInputStream first100Bytes = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
   // pass first100bytes to your clients
```

If you don't want to use `DataInputStream.readFully`, there is `IOUtils.readFully` from apache commons-io, or you can implment the read loop explicitly.

If you have more advanced needs, such as reading from a segment in the middle of the file, or larger amounts of data, then extending InputStream and overriding the read(byte[], int,int) as well as read(), will give you better performance than just overriding the read() method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use guava's ByteStreams.
Notice that you should use skipFully() before limit, for example:

```
ByteStreams.skipFully(tmpStream, range.start());
tmpStream = ByteStreams.limit(tmpStream, range.length());
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2888427/2780808) solution, using the `skip` method of an `InputStream`, you can also read a range starting in the middle of the file.

```
public class RangeInputStream extends InputStream
{
    private InputStream parent;
    private long remaining;

    public RangeInputStream(InputStream parent, long start, long end) throws IOException
    {
        if (end < start)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("end < start");
        }

        if (parent.skip(start) < start)
        {
            throw new IOException("Unable to skip leading bytes");
        }

        this.parent=parent;
        remaining = end - start;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException
    {
        return --remaining >= 0 ? parent.read() : -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was solved a similar problem for my project, you can see the working code here [PartInputStream](https://gist.github.com/develjs/5e808f7a70fe240f2a3e23ba07aea05d).
I was used it for assets and files input streams. But it is not suitable for а streams whose length is not available initially, such as network streams.