# Error while using Google Drive API when the specified file is already open in read only mode

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

```
mFileId = (DriveId) data.getParcelableExtra(
            OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
Log.e("file id", mFileId.getResourceId() + "");
DriveFile file = mFileId.asDriveFile();
try {
    results =  file.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).await();//this is to return a driveContent object

DriveContents contents = results.getDriveContents();
```

This is the error it gives when that file should be opened in readonly mode, but the file is already open in readonly mode

> InputStream in=contents.getInputStream();

Comment: Try using results.getParcelFileDescriptor() and creating an input stream yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `java.io.File.setReadOnly()` to set a file to readonly. Also check whether the file has been created or exists first and then set the read only flag.

```
File file = new File("C:/path/file.txt");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.setReadOnly();
    } else {
        System.out.println("File does not exists.");
    }
```

Check these related threads and this [example](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java) from the documentation:

- [how to set read only access for file using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947389/how-to-set-read-only-access-for-file-using-java)
- [How can I create constrained InputStream to read only part of the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888335/how-can-i-create-constrained-inputstream-to-read-only-part-of-the-file)

Comment: This thing won't resolve my issue because I got that id from drive which means that file exits